# cannot change permission of a dir

Tags: permissions, transmission

I mounted a windows folder into my ubuntu so i could just drop my `.torrent` files

```
//192.168.1.61/shared/torrent on /root/downloads/torrents type cifs (rw)
```

but, whenever i put `.torrent` file inside my /torrent folder, i get this error [/var/log/messages]

```
- Watching "/root/downloads/torrents" for new .torrent files (daemon.c:555)
- Using inotify to watch directory "/root/downloads/torrents" (watch.c:73)
- Unable to watch "/root/downloads/torrents": Permission denied (watch.c:79)
```

so, i turned off the `tranmission-daemon` service and went inside ubuntu torrent files

```
root@media:~/downloads# ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 root debian-transmission 4096 May 26 20:28 complete
drwxrwxr-x 2 root debian-transmission 4096 May 26 20:28 incomplete
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark root                   0 May 27  2013 torrents
```

noticed that my torrent folder is not **grouped** with my root. so i issued this command

```
root@server#: usermod -a -G debian-transmission root
root@server#: chgrp -R debian-transmission /root/downloads/torrents
root@server#: -R 775 /root/downloads/torrents
```

but it failed to modify the `/torrent` folder.

```
root@media:~/downloads# ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 root debian-transmission 4096 May 26 20:28 complete
drwxrwxr-x 2 root debian-transmission 4096 May 26 20:28 incomplete
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark root                   0 May 27  2013 torrents <<--- THIS
```

in my windows folder i have allowed the shared folder to [read/write/exec].

so my question is, why cant i change the group and owner of my `/root/download/torrents`

Comment: Why are you using `/root` for this? Using your personal folder in `/home` would be better. Even better if you created a new partition (FAT32 formatted) so that both Windows and Ubuntu could see it. In particular using the root account for this is kind of not recommended.

Comment: I have to agree with @edwin about this: using `root` is not recommended on Ubuntu. Anyway.. some of your commands are malformed. If you want to change ownership of the `../torrents` folder you need to `chown -R root /root/downloads/torrents` and `chgrp -R debian-transmission /root/downloads/torrents` then `chmod -R 755 /root/downloads/torrents`

Comment: i see, ok ill go try your suggestion

Comment: ok, so i managed to change my directory from `/root` to `/home/mark/torrents` and the necessary changes in `mount` and inside the configurations. but permission for the folder **/home/mark/torrents** is still `drwxr-xr-x 2 zild root                4096 May 27  2013 torrents`

Comment: And the `/home/mark/torrents` folder is the CIFS-mounted share? The permissions are correct (755), but why the change in the owner of the folder from __mark__ to __zild__?

Comment: apology `zild` user was a typo. that was my other user. but your solution to change from `/root/downloads/` to `/home/mark/` solved my issue. i didnt realized that its weird to use `/root/` for personal folders.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the ownership of SAMBA mounts.  You must mount them with the correct UID and GID.

`sudo vim /etc/fstab`

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs   uid=ubuntuuser,gid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm   0       0
```

More information available [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)